# Tensorflow distributed inference

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, multi-gpu

I have a large model (GPT-J 6B) and two 16G GPUs (V100 with no NVLink). I would like to do inference (generation). GPT-J needs 24G memory, so I need to split the model across my two GPUs.
For me, simplicity is much more important than maximizing utilization/throughput.

What is the easiest way to distribute the network?  Is it possible to put first half of the network on one GPU and the second half on the other? (pipeline-parallel essentially)

Comment: What is the framework? Jax, Pytorch, Tensorflow? What is your batch size?

Comment: @ValentinGoldité It's Tensorflow as the title suggests. I would like to do autoregressive generation, so sequence at a time is good.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I can't help in Tensorflow